# Connect to MariaDb datasource in Power Bi

Tags: mariadb, microsoft-powerbi

I have successfully connected to my MariaDb/MySQL datasource in *Power Bi Desktop* using the *Oracle MariaDB ODBC connector*.

I use Import mode to be able to model the imported data in Power Bi. So far, this works as I want....

**Now** I want to publish my file to the *Web based Power Bi workspace* to be able to share my work with my colleagues. Publishing works but I would like to use a schedule to update my data online.

On manual updates on the Web based Power Bi I get the following error:

```
Unable to refresh the model (id=61320) because it references an unsupported data source.
```

I can also try to "Identify data sources" on the Data source page, I'm getting the error:

```
Information: Query contains unknown function name: MariaDB.Contents.
```

A simple question that I can't get answered is if only the desktop version can access MariaDB/MySQL data or if there is a solution?

Comment: You might want to try configuring a Personal Data Gateway. What it will do, is connect from the PowerBI cloud via your computer to update the data.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran Thanks, but that would require me to have my computer running to update data, and that is not sufficient, I need the data to run an update schedule without dependencies.